# remove messy image tag on dom ready and set proper using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using tiny mce editor to format content and also for aligning images. After setting image align when looking html source my code snippet looks like this

```
<img width="200" height="100" alt="" src="/images/SomeImage.jpg" left;"="">
```

So I tried to put javascript on the bottom of my page to remove image left attribut and to put proper attribute like this

```
$('img[left\\;]').removeAttr('left').attr("align","left");
```

But my image remains the same (without proper align).
How to remove this messy image tag and set proper on dom ready.

p.s. please do not advise me to investigate why is rendered like this on the first place.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for you...

```
$("img").each(function() {
    this.outerHTML = this.outerHTML.replace('left;"=""', '');
});
```

It gets the raw html for every image and does a replace on the dodgy attribute you have.  As long as you know for sure that it will always be that exact text then this will resolve it.

There is another issue though, that may or may not cause problems.  The image tag is not closed correctly.  I assume this is also a bug in the editor, but obviously can't say for sure without knowing more.

Comment: that for sure will fix it